# pandas dataframe column transformation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, calculated-columns

My input df is as below:

```
ID     item1       item2        item3
1      a,b         b,c          b
2      a,c,f       b,c          b,c,f
3      g,h,i       i            h,i
4      j,k         j,k          l
```

df datatypes for item1, item2 and item3 are string type.

I would like to add a 4th column and transformation required is as below:
pseudo code:

`Final_item  = item3 - set[col(item1) + col(item2)]`
Basically, in the last column, is adding item1 and item2, then apply set to remove duplicates then subtract with item3 column.

Desired output as below:

```
ID     item1       item2        item3       Final_item
1      a,b         b,c          b           a,c
2      a,c,f       b,c          b,c,f       a 
3      g,h,i       i            h,i         g
4      j,k         j,k          l           j,k
```

Comment: What columns are subtracted?

Comment: Temp = Add item1+item2, then remove duplicates.  Then item3 - Temp (subtraction)  to find the Final_item column.  Thanks

Comment: My solution working? if not, why `g,h` is for 3rd row in output?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited.

Comment: OK, so my answer working nice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `split` columns and also joined columns by `,` and then get difference in list comprehension of zipped Series:

```
i3 = df['item3'].str.split(',')
i12 = (df['item1'] + ',' + df['item2']).str.split(',')
df['Final_item'] = [','.join(set(b) - set(a)) for a, b in zip(i3, i12)]
print (df)
   ID  item1 item2  item3 Final_item
0   1    a,b   b,c      b        c,a
1   2  a,c,f   b,c  b,c,f          a
2   3  g,h,i     i    h,i          g
3   4    j,k   j,k      l        j,k
```

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm. As I am converting pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe, I had to explicitly change the data type as ```df['item1'] = test['item1'].astype(str)```  for all teh columns as teh first step.

Comment: But I have problem with the dataset. Some of the item2 values are ```none``` and it gets printed on Final_item data also.For example if item2 value is None, Final_item column gets the value as ```None,a,h```

Comment: Thanks, I replaced `None` with empty string.